# fb:like url parameter value is removed. Title also incomplete

Tags: url, parameters, title, facebook-like

I've added a facebook like button to my page but it doesn't record the given url properly. The problem is that the url displayed on my facebook profile, after I click the like button, is missing a parameter value. The title displayed next to the url is also missing some parts.
Here's how I configured my facebook like button:

```
<head>
.....
<meta property="og:title" content="Family Tree of John Doe"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="mySite:family_tree"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.mySite.com/edit/tree/visual?person=John_Doe_1"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://images.mySite.com/tree.png"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="mySite"/>
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="................"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="Site description"/>
....
<head>
<body>
.....
<fb:like href="http://www.mySite.com/edit/tree/visual?person=John_Doe_1" show_faces="true" width="450"></fb:like>
.....
</body>
```

In the profile page the like section has the title "Family Tree of" and the url it points to is "http://www.mySite.com/edit/tree/visual?person".
How do I solve this issue?